Rewrite a c++ variable declaration code through AST
I'm currently trying to rewrite a c++ code from
Query q(
      "SELECT %LC FROM %T WHERE %W",
      getColumnArray(),
      "table_name",
      buildConstraints(id, "abc");

to
auto q = QueryBuilder.from("table_name").select(getColumnArray()).where(id,"abc").build();

I'm able to grab the target code block using
varDecl(isExpansionInMainFile(),hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("Query"))))

However, I think there are additional improvements/requirements I may need help to understand:

Would it be possible to match a Query where the argument contains "SELECT"?
Once I have the target code block, how do I extract the arguments of the variable constructor (e.g., getColumnArray(), "table_name", etc.) to be able to reuse them in the new code?
Would it be possible to get the wrapper function name of the matcher-matched code block?


Are those clang matchers? Might want to edit that into your question...

You previously asked about the string literals; the answer to that part remains no, you can't do that with matchers alone.  Q2 is certainly possible, and Q3 probably is (but I don't understand the question), but what is not clear is what setup you are using to run whatever code you are writing.  Are you using clang-query exclusively?  Did you write a C++ check using the Clang API?  Something else (Python? C?)?  Without knowing more about the tools you are using, it is very difficult to answer.

@ScottMcPeak Yes, it's a clang query.

I take it you are running the query in the question using clang-query.  But you also state that your goal is to rewrite C++ code, and clang-query cannot do that; it merely finds instances that match a given expression and prints them to the console.  To rewrite C++ code, you need to use one of the Clang APIs such as Libtooling for C++ or Python libclang.
Nevertheless, I'll answer the questions for a pure clang-query context.  See the AST Matcher Reference for more information (albeit terse) on the individual matchers.
Q1: Filtering on string literals
clang-query cannot filter on the contents of string literals, as asked and answered previously.
Q2a: Getting the constructor arguments
Having matched a varDecl, use hasInitializer(cxxConstructExpr(hasArgument(...))) to get the arguments passed to the constructor.
This assumes there are a fixed number of arguments.
Q2b: Getting arguments for a variable-argument callee
In comments it was clarified that the Query class constructor takes
a variable number of arguments, presumably something like:
class Query {
public:
  Query(char const *fmt, ...);
  ...
};

If all of the parameters had names and types, then we could use
forEachArgumentWithParam, but they don't.  So, instead, we have to
use a sequence of optionally(hasArgument(N, ...)) for N up to some
large but fixed limit.
Q3: Getting the containing function
Having matched a varDecl, use hasAncestor(functionDecl()) to get the definition of the containing function.
Example query for Q2 and Q3
Here is a shell script that runs clang-query and demonstrates the answers to Q2 and Q3:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin:$PATH

query='m

  varDecl(
    isExpansionInMainFile(),
    hasType(cxxRecordDecl(hasName("S"))),
    hasInitializer(
      cxxConstructExpr(
        optionally(
          hasArgument(0,
            expr().bind("arg0")
          )
        ),
        optionally(
          hasArgument(1,
            expr().bind("arg1")
          )
        ),
        optionally(
          hasArgument(2,
            expr().bind("arg2")
          )
        ),
        optionally(
          hasArgument(3,
            expr().bind("arg3")
          )
        ),
        optionally(
          hasArgument(4,
            expr().bind("arg4")
          )
        ),
        optionally(
          hasArgument(5,
            expr().bind("arg5")
          )
        ),
        optionally(
          hasArgument(6,
            expr().bind("arg6")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    hasAncestor(
      functionDecl().bind("containingFunction")
    )
  ).bind("varDecl")

'

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 filename.cc -- <compile options like -I, etc.>"
  exit 2
fi

# Run the query.  Setting 'bind-root' to false means clang-query will
# not also print a redundant "root" binding.
clang-query \
  -c="set bind-root false" \
  -c="$query" \
  "$@"

# EOF

When run on the input:
struct S {
  S(...);
};

void f()
{
  S s1(0,1);
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
}

it produces the output:
$ ./cmd.sh test.cc --

Match #1:

$PWD/test.cc:7:8: note: "arg0" binds here
  S s1(0,1);
       ^
$PWD/test.cc:7:10: note: "arg1" binds here
  S s1(0,1);
         ^
$PWD/test.cc:5:1: note: "containingFunction" binds here
void f()
^~~~~~~~
$PWD/test.cc:7:3: note: "varDecl" binds here
  S s1(0,1);
  ^~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

$PWD/test.cc:8:8: note: "arg0" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
       ^
$PWD/test.cc:8:10: note: "arg1" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
         ^
$PWD/test.cc:8:12: note: "arg2" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
           ^
$PWD/test.cc:8:14: note: "arg3" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
             ^
$PWD/test.cc:8:16: note: "arg4" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
               ^
$PWD/test.cc:8:18: note: "arg5" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
                 ^
$PWD/test.cc:8:20: note: "arg6" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
                   ^
$PWD/test.cc:5:1: note: "containingFunction" binds here
void f()
^~~~~~~~
$PWD/test.cc:8:3: note: "varDecl" binds here
  S s2(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 matches.

In the example, it stops at six arguments because that is as far as the
query goes, but more optionally(hasArgument(N, ...)) can be added as
needed.

Wow, thank you for such detailed answer. I'll definitely try it on my local machine. I'll get back to you if I encounter any other issues.

@LunaticJape Reminder: If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can click the "accept" checkmark so others know it is not still open.

Sorry I still have a question, if the number of arguments is dynamic, how do I bind each of them to a name?
